# Simple vLAN setup

Tags: windows, hyper-v, vlan

I have a basic lab environment set up to try and get 2 vLANs working in hyper-v.

I have the following equipment

- 1 hyper-v server
- 1 Desktop PC
- 1 Managed Switch (d-link DES-3052P)
- 1 cheap router (DI-604)

My end goal is to have 1 VM and the desktop on one vLAN with internet, and 1 VM on a separate vLAN with internet access.

I am having troubles getting an internet connection to both vLANs. The switch does not have the ability to have asynchronous vLANs.

This is my switch configuration

- Port 1 - Trunk Port  - Connected to router
- Port 2 - Trunk Port  - Connected to hyper-v Server
- Port 3 - Access Port- Connected to Desktop

Within hyper-v I have 1 switch and 2 VMs. When the VMs are set up to use vlan ID 1, everything works fine. As soon as a VM is set up to use vlan ID 2, they lose all network connection and cannot communicate with the router anymore. I believe this is because the router is not vLAN aware.

Can anyone help me with what settings need to be set up on my switch? I believe I want an egress rule so traffic leaving towards the router is untagged, is that right? If not, any ideas or hints as to what needs to be set up?

Answer (score 0):

This seems similar to [VLAN Configuration for Home Network](https://superuser.com/questions/1326689/vlan-configuration-for-home-network) in that you want two separate VLANs with Internet access through a router that is not VLAN-aware.  Your situation is a little more complicated due to the virtualization of two machines and a switch, but I think the basic problem is similar.

I'd suggest you try the technique proposed in the other question and create a new VLAN that spans all ports on both switches.  Set pvids for the desktop and VMs to be 1 (if on VLAN 1) and 2 (if on VLAN 2), and pvid=3 for the router, and set the router connection to "untagged" as you suggested.  VLAN 3 allows all requests to go out to the router (and Internet).  The pvid settings prevent cross-VLAN communication.  However, any device that connects directly to the router will have access to both VLANs, so you don't have complete VLAN isolation.

I can't vouch for the security of this approach, but for a lab setup it might help you accomplish your goal of allowing Internet access to both VLANs without a VLAN-aware router.