# VLAN Configuration for Home Network

Tags: networking, security, switch, vlan

I would like to provide some separation of devices in my home network using a managed switch.  I've read other related questions/answers, but they have different requirements that get into VLAN routers or other equipment because they want different VLANs to talk to each other.  I just want separation, and I want to know if I can do everything with a single managed switch.

- **My goals:**

  1. Isolate Internet-accessible server from rest of network to prevent compromised server from attacking internal nodes.
  2. Isolate computer used for sensitive data from rest of network.
  3. Allow all devices access to Internet.
  4. Restrict switch management to a single port.
- **My planned switch configuration:**

  - **VLAN:**

    - **10:** ports 1 - 47 (Internet access)
    - **20:** ports 1 and 2 (server)
    - **30:** ports 1 and 3 - 46 (home devices)
    - **40:** ports 1 and 47 (sensitive data machine)
    - **50:** port 48 (switch management)
  - **Port:**

    - **1:** *untagged*, `pvid=10`  (connected to Internet router)
    - **2:** *untagged*, `pvid=20` (connected to server)
    - **3 - 46:** *untagged*, `pvid=30` (connected to home machines)
    - **47:** *untagged*, `pvid=40` (connected to sensitive data machine)
    - **48:** *untagged*, `pvid=50` (connected to switch management machine)

In addition, the router is configured to forward port 80 to the server machine, which has a static IP address.  The router uses DHCP to assign IP addresses to the rest of the machines.

When I set the switch up this way things seem to work, in the sense that I can access the Internet from machines on ports 2-47, I can access the server (through the external facing IP address of the router) from other VLANs, and I can't seem to access any other machines across VLANs.  However, I've read some best practices such as the following:

1. Each VLAN is a different IP subnet
2. Access ports (e.g., 2-47) should be members of a single VLAN
3. Use tagging-aware router to filter traffic across VLANs

In my setup, I use a single IP subnet.  I only have ~20 devices, so there is no issue with size, but I'm curious if there are other issues.  For example, could different devices on different VLANs get the same IP address, and if so, would this be a problem?  My understanding is that this is OK because they can't access each other, but if they both send Internet requests could the responses get mixed up?

In my setup, I also use VLAN 10 across nearly all ports as a way to allow Internet access.  Is this a problem?  It seems like maybe someone could use this VLAN to hop VLANs (e.g., compromised server to access home machines, or home machines to access sensitive data machine).  Does the combination of *untagged* and `pvid=X` prevent this sort of behavior?  Would a VLAN tag of 10 get rejected from a port other than Port 1 with this setup?

My router is the standard Verizon router, and I don't know how it handles VLAN tagging (probably not at all?).  Is there any problem if it actually does handle tags (e.g., insecure defaults) or if it doesn't (e.g., allows routing between VLANs due to lack of knowledge about them)?

Is this an appropriate configuration for my goals, or do I need to change things or introduce more equipment to properly isolate and secure the network?

Comment: What is the make and model of the switch?

Comment: The switch is an Avaya 5520-48T-PWR.

Comment: Consider putting OpenWRT on your router (if that is possible with the standard Verizon router) to make it VLAN capable.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this without a VLAN capable router/firewall . There are multiple reasons for this, one of which is that your server needs internet access while not being being directly accessible to other devices which also need Internet access, meaning a router/firewall is needed to interface the 2 types of devices.

If you think of each VLAN as a virtual unmanaged switch you will be well on your way to understanding the problem - it either the ports are connected and can freely transmit to each other, or they are not connected and can't see each other - there are no half measures.

You really need subnets and routing - if you put machines on different vlans in the same subnet they will not be able to find or talk to each other. Thus even if you have a router, the machines won't know to speak to it when trying to reach other machines, and indeed won't be able to see it in most cases.

An untagged port can be viewed as a port with a "default" tag - when you have a port with multiple tags, it carries the data inside tagged packets, so the router needs to know how to remove the tags for data to be interpreted. This is generally done by having a separate IP address per VLAN on the router, with each address in the associated subnet used by the VLAN.

(I note I've simplified things a bit, and an expert may be able to break some rules above in some cases - but you really need to understand all the above and how it fits together before you can do this - and breaking the rules is not generally good design either.

Similarly, while in practice VLANS do provide security, using VLANS as a security measure is a bit contovertial to some experts)

Comment: davidgo, you mention that its all-or-nothing (no half measures), but I think that's exactly what I want.  I don't want VLANs 20, 30, or 40 to be able to talk to each other.  I just want to provide Internet access to all of them.  This is working with my configuration as described, but it seems to violate some best practices, so I'm concerned there may be some hidden pitfalls.

Comment: @juhraffe, this is a decent answer. the only other way to do what you want would be a router that has multiple physical interfaces that are configurable. Or just go the ol pfsense/opensense route. A router with ACL's will give you much better control of each network in either case

Comment: @juhraffe - I am skeptical that that you can do this with a half measure, and I'm very skeptical that your VLANS are correctly set up if this is working in your setup - and by working I mean including Internet access and the "firewalling" as you believe to be happening through your VLANS.   If you have somehow fluked something (if it were working and not a fluke you would not be asking a question here), and it will come back and bite you/whoever comes after you hard.  You really,really don't want to use half measures to achieve these goals.

Comment: @Tim and davidgo, I agree davidgo's solution is a good one.  Using a VLAN-aware router would not only provide what I want, but also the ability to filter traffic between VLANs.  However, I'm still trying to figure out where my proposed solution breaks down.  My limited testing shows that everyone can get to the Internet, and no one can hop VLANs.  Is there a simple test that would confirm that the VLANs are not isolated?

Comment: @juhraffe, use NMAP to scan whole subnets from each vlan. Scan vlan 20,30&40 from vlan10. 10,30,40 from vlan20 etc. See what comes up, I would scan both tcp/udp when you do.

Comment: @Tim, using nmap from VLANs 20, 30, and 40 I see the router and machine(s) on the same VLAN but not the machines on the other VLANs.  However, I also see machines connected directly to the router through Wi-Fi.  That definitely breaks my isolation goals.  However, it seems like I could fix this by disabling the router Wi-Fi and connecting APs to the switch on VLAN 30.  I'm still not convinced there isn't a way to cross VLANs, but the nmap scans I'm seeing match the desired VLAN isolation goals.

Comment: I attached to the router Wi-Fi and nmap found all the machines on all VLANs.  I could connect from Wi-Fi to VLAN and VLAN to Wi-Fi.  So, it looks like the only isolation I'm getting from the VLANs is between the VLANs themselves, but VLAN-to-nonVLAN connections are wide open.  I still think I might be able to disable the router Wi-Fi and connect everything through the switch to get isolation.  However, this would be risky because enabling router Wi-Fi (perhaps upon reset or by accident) would compromise the entire network.

Comment: @juhraffe, don't jump through hoops over it. Get a router.

Answer (score 1):

You will need more equipment. If the router is not capable of having more than one VLAN on your inside Network, than there is no way for all the VLANs to be able to get to the Internet, only one of them will be able to get to the Internet (the one VLAN where the router is plugged into).

Comment: Abu Zaid, What you say is true if I eliminate VLAN 10 and plug the router into one of VLAN 20, 30, or 40.  However, with VLAN 10 spanning all ports, I am able to simultaneously access the Internet from VLANs 20, 30, and 40 when I plug the router into VLAN 10.

Comment: It could only be one of the two. If you are able to access the Internet from all the VLANs, than they are not isolated at all. I assume you only have one connection from the Router back to the Switch, so the Router could be part of only one VLAN, in your case 10.

Comment: There is only one connection to the router through port 1 (VLANs 10, 20, 30, and 40), and my fear is that you're right about the lack of isolation.  Can you help me see how the VLANs are not isolated?  Ping requests and HTTP requests across VLANs fail now.  Is there another simple test that would show, for example, that a machine on port 3 (VLANs 10 and 30) *is* accessible from the server on port 2 (VLANs 10 and 20)?

Comment: If you can ping Router from each VLAN, then they are not isolated. Now, I am not sure what you mean when you say "Port 3 (VLANs 10 and 30). Does the port belong to VLAN 10 or VLAN 30?

Comment: VLAN 10 includes ports 1-47 and VLAN 30 includes ports 3-46, so port 3 is a member of both VLAN 10 and VLAN 30.  The pvid on port 3 is set to 30, so untagged traffic from the machine attached to port 3 will be sent to VLAN 30, which will reach the router (which is on port 1, also a member of VLAN 30).  Responses from the router will come into port 1, which has pvid 10, and these will be able to make it back to the requester on port 3, which is also a member of VLAN 10.

Comment: So the router would receive traffic on VLAN 30 and send it Back on VLAN 10? Is that what you are assuming?

Comment: I think the switch internally uses VLAN 30 to send the request to the router, but it strips the VLAN tag because all ports are set to be untagged.  The router response goes to the requester using VLAN 10 in a similar manner.

Comment: There can only be one untagged VLAN on a port. For example, if router is getting traffic for VLAN 30 untagged, then it will not be able to send untagged traffic back to Switch on VLAN 10. Based on the information you have provided so far, it looks like all the traffic is untagged and sharing same VLAN, which would defeat the purpose of isolation. The best solution would be to get a router which supports VLANs and then configure one Subnet for each VLAN to isolate the traffic.

Comment: My switch gives me four options for tagging: tagAll (trunk), untagAll (access), tagPvidOnly, and untagPvidOnly.  I selected untagAll (access) for all ports.

Comment: OK, then I would suggest removing VLAN 10 from all Ports, and see if it still works. If it does, then you do have Isolated your VLANs.

Comment: When I remove VLAN 10 I lose Internet on all remaining VLANs.  If I connect the router to a different port (e.g., port 5 with pvid = 30) or reconfigure the pvid on port 1 (the router connection) to be a particular VLAN, I get Internet on that VLAN but not the others.

Comment: OK, so the VLANs are not isolated, since it only works if everything is on VLAN 10. At this point, I would say that the better option is to get a router that supports Trunk Port (tagged VLAN), and assign each VLAN/Segment a separate IP Subnet.